# What is the probability that being dealt 7 cards from a standard deck they take the form AAABBBC

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

To be clear I want to know if the hand could be arranged that way; the cards do not to come out in that order. They could also take the form AABABCB. Ex. (3,hearts)(3,clubs)(3,spades)(jack,diamonds)(jack,spades)(jack,hearts)(5,spades) And that would also qualify.

Comment: When you say AAABBBC, those letters refer to the value of the card (ace, 2, ..., king), not the suit, right? Also, is C allowed to be equal to either A or B, or should it be distinct?

Comment: This is *very* similar to the question of counting the number of "two-pair" hands in 5-card poker.  Have you seen that problem?

Comment: Assuming `C` must be a different rank than either of `A` or `B`, pick the ranks used for `A` and `B` *simultaneously* (*since `AAABBBC` is otherwise the same to us as `BBBAAAC`*).  Call the smaller of the ranks chosen `A`.  Now, pick which suit wasn't used for `A` (*equivalently, pick the three suits which were used*).  Pick which suit wasn't used for `B`.  Finally, pick the rank and suit of `C`.  Apply multiplication principle and conclude.

Comment: The only difference between this and what I marked this as a duplicate of is that we are picking seven cards instead of five and picking three suits to be used for each of the triples rather than just two suits to be used for each of the pairs.

Comment: Thank you J. I apologize yes it is very similar. So it should be (13C2 * 4C3 * 4C3  * 11C1 * 4C1) / 52C7 I think.

Comment: That is correct